# Uncaught ReferenceError: createReactClass is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I follow a tutorial about `ReactJS` using `watchify` and `babelify`. I use `react@16` version and I am aware `React.createReactClass` is deprecated. I need temporary fix to get rid of `Uncaught ReferenceError: createReactClass is not defined` error.

I have installed `create-react-class` package. my package.json is :

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "watchify src/app.js  -o public/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ react es2015 ] ]",
    "server": "cd public; live-server --port=1234 --entry-file=index.html"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^8.0.0",
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "watchify": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.16"
  }
}
```

and my `app.js` is

```
const Sidebar =  createReactClass({
  render(){
    let props = this.props;

    return (<div className='sidebar'>
      <h2> All Decks </h2>
      <ul>
      {props.decs.map((deck, i)=> 
        <li key={i}> {deck.name}</li>
      )}
      </ul>
      { props.addingDeck && <input ref='add'/> }
    </div>);
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<App>
  <Sidebar decks={[ { name: 'Deck 1' }]} addingDeck={false} />
</App>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

How can I make createReactClass work ?
Thanks

edit : I cant import using " `var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');`" . may be file is not an jsx file.

Comment: `var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');`

Comment: I tried that it breaks npm run build . without that script works.

Comment: Silly question, but did you make sure to add create-react-class to your dependencies?

Comment: @MEnf did you check my dependencies in package.json , I think I have it.

Comment: *"I cant import using"* Why?

Comment: @FelixKling npm run build fails I am not sure about the reason

Comment: *"I am not sure about the reason"* You certainly should find out.

Comment: @FelixKling I am reading the logs about error but I cant find any particular , shall I paste  them  in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stateful components you want to extend the Component class from React...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
class Sidebar extends Component {
  render(){
    let props = this.props;

    return (<div className='sidebar'>
      <h2> All Decks </h2>
      <ul>
      {props.decs.map((deck, i)=> 
        <li key={i}> {deck.name}</li>
      )}
      </ul>
      { props.addingDeck && <input ref='add'/> }
    </div>);
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<App>
  <Sidebar decks={[ { name: 'Deck 1' }]} addingDeck={false} />
</App>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: While this is the more current way to do it, I'm not entirely sure this answers the question he asked.

Comment: I was responding to "I need temporary fix to get rid of Uncaught ReferenceError: createReactClass is not defined error." You might be right :D

Comment: Yeah, I would encourage you to check out babel and the new es7 syntax. 
 Using it makes react code a lot easier to write!  Facebook even uses it as the default syntax in their boiler plate code. https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app